# PHP Factory class with variable number of arguments

Tags: php, oop, factory

I'm to make a (sort of) factory class that accepts a variable number of arguments and passes them on to the class that it will be invoking

```
<?php

class A {
    private $a;
    private $b;
    private $c;
    public function __construct($a=1, $b=2, $c=3){
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
    }
}

class B {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct(){
        $args = func_get_args();
        $this->foo = call_user_func_array(array('A', '__construct'), $args);
    }

    public function getObject(){
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$b = new B(10, 20, 30);  
var_dump($b->getObject()); // should return equivalent of new A(10,20,30);
```

I'm getting this error

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method A::__construct() cannot be called statically
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this answer reading about [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php). This seems to work best

```
<?php
class Factory {
    # ...
    public function __construct(){
        $args = func_get_args();
        $a = new ReflectionClass('A');
        $this->foo = $a->newInstanceArgs($args);
    }
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$class = "A";
$foo = new $class(1, 2, 56); // i think this not solve your problem
```

Or use **ReflectionClass** or maybe constructor injection with property injection.

Comment: This is still passing in a static amount of variables. Thanks for the ReflectionClass pointer though; that led to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should solve the problem by not passing the values into the constructor, but rather by chaining.

```
class MyFactory() {
    public $data;

    public static function factory( $data = null ) {
        return new MyFactory( $data );
    }
    public function addArgument( $argValue ) {
        $this->data[] = $argValue;
        return $this;
    }

    public function doSomeFunction() {
        $data = $this->data; //is an array, so you can loop through and do whatever.
        /* now your arbitrarily long array of data points can be used to do whatever. */
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
$factory = MyFactory::factory();
$factory
    ->addArgument( '21' )
    ->addArgument( '903' )
    ->addArgument( '1' )
    ->addArgument( 'abc' )
    ->addArgument( 'jackson' )
    ->doSomeFunction();
```

I hope that at least gets you headed in a useful direction. You can do all sorts of crazy stuff with this type of pattern.

Comment: Kristian, this is a great answer, but unfortunately I cannot modify the `A` class in my example.  the B class is going to serve as a wrapper for it that also instantiates it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, According to the php doc first example: https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array

```
$this->foo = call_user_func_array(array(new A, '__construct'), $args);
```

Comment: @Truth What are u talking about? There is a difference by asking a new object vs asking for a static function new A vs A::Function

Comment: Then why does PHP.net advise it to do it that way?

Comment: this doesn't work though if `A` has any mandatory arguments in the constructor as `new A` will attempt to construct a new object before `call_user_func_array` gets a chance to send my `$args` to it.  See the above answer for PHP's actual solution to this problem.